# Docker-compose - Nginx setup for Localhost multi applications

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose

It's my first time with nginx to orchestrate services for my dev environment. Looks simple but it doesn't want work. I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

The idea is to run 2 applications : prestashop and dashboard, with ssl access passing through nginx reverse proxy.

Here is the docker-compose.yml code

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.19.10-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    depends_on:
      - prestashop
      - dashboard
  prestashop:
    image: mitlabs/apache-php7.0
    volumes:
      - ./prestashop/:/var/www/html
    links:
      - 'mariadb'
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    volumes:
      - ./ps-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      TZ: "America/Chicago"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "AngeloOsradar"
      MYSQL_USER: 'osradar'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'osradarpss'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'webmaster_prestaxexpressiveedev'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
  dashboard:
    image: mitlabs/apache-php7.0
    volumes:
      - ./dashboard/:/var/www/html
```

and the nginx.conf file

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost:8080;
    return 301 https://localhost:8080$request_uri;
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost:8080;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://prestashop;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost:8083;
    return 301 https://localhost:8083$request_uri;
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost:8083;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://dashboard;
    }
  }
}
```

The cert is created with mkcert
`mkcert -cert-file localhost.crt -key-file localhost.key localhost`

It's certainly a little thing that block the engine.
Thanks for your help to see it.